# String vararg and String array

Tags: java, string

probably this has been already asked multiple times but still my doubt is not clear:

i have a method like this:

```
public Object getConfig(String... names) {
```

and when i call it as:

**case 1:**
`configService.getConfig("str1", "str2", "str3"); // it works`

**case 2:**

```
String[] names = {"str1","str2","str3"}; // it works
       configService.getConfig(names);
```

**case3:**
but when i try  following it does not work

```
String[] names = {"str1","str2","str3"};
configService.getConfig("randomString",names);
```

As i understand we are passing getConfig(String,String[]) which is String ... args  and i expected it to work.

I do not understand why ?

Comment: Because it doesn't. You have to choose between either case 1 or case 2; the compiler just doesn't handle case 3. Why? At a guess, because it's just another case that wasn't perceived to carry its weight. If you support this, then why not support `getConfig("", names, "", names)`?

Comment: Your "randomString" and your `String[] names` are two different objects, but the method only take one object, which is a String varargs

Comment: Varargs is already causing problems with polymorphic methods, this would create even more ambiguity.

Comment: (String,String[]) is not the same as (String...)

Comment: Did you get it working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Varargs is [syntactic sugar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar) that compiles this syntax:

```
myMethod("foo", "bar", "baz");

void myMethod(String... args) {
    //
}
```

as if it were:

```
myMethod(new String[] {"foo", "bar", "baz"});

void myMethod(String[] args) {
    //
}
```

And because the method's parameter type is compiled as `myMethod(String[] args)`, you can explicitly pass it an array.

However, in java there is no magic "concatenation" of elements and arrays to form a single larger array, which is what you're attempting to do.

---

AFAIK there's no simple way to make what you are trying to do work in one statement.

Answer (score 2):

`getConfig(String... names)` method signature is equal to `getConfig(String[] names)`,
but not to `getConfig(String name, String[] names)`. That's it.

You can add an overloaded `getConfig(String name, String[] names)` that would collect all your arguments to a string array and call the original `getConfig(String... names)` afterwords.

Comment: That's a very good explanation, but it doesn't explain how to achieve the wanted result

Comment: You can add an overloaded getConfig that would collect all your arguments to a string array and call the original getConfig(String... names) afterwords.

Comment: You're right, but I meant you should add that to your answer

Answer (score 1):

Your method needs an array as a parameter or a sequence of strings. You're trying to pass two parameters, a string and an array.

Do this instead:

```
String[] names = {"str1","str2","str3"};
String[] namesX = new String[names.length+1];
for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
    namesX[i+1] = names[i];
}
namesX[0] = "randomString";
configService.getConfig(namesX);
```